# Upgrade to Spring Boot 2.2.0 throws ClassNotFoundException: : org.springframework.integration.handler.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolversHolder

Tags: spring-boot

I wrote my application with Spring Boot 2.1.6 and everything was working fine. But when I upgraded Spring Boot from 2.1.6 to 2.2.0 and I am seeing the exception below. I am using Spring Cloud Greenwich.SR3. Has any one encountered this before?

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.integration.handler.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolversHolder
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 86 more

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use Spring Cloud Hoxton with Spring Boot 2.2.x. There's a table in the release train section of the [Spring Cloud project page](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud) that shows which version of Spring Cloud to use with which version of Spring Boot. At the time of writing, it shows the following:

```
Release Train  |  Boot Version
-------------  |  ------------
Hoxton         |  2.2.x
Greenwich      |  2.1.x
Finchley       |  2.0.x
Edgware        |  1.5.x
Dalston        |  1.5.x
```

Comment: Using Spring Cloud Hoxton with Spring Boot 2.2.x helped. Thanks Andy